# How to implement a configurable-interval 'keepalive' signal whenever a source is silent?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a 'source' that sends items to a target over the network. In order to track the connection status of the target, whenever there are no items to send, the source should send a 'keepalive' signal every `TimeSpan`.

```
                       |time>
source    x----x---x--x--------------------------x---x---x-x--x
                             |time>|time>|time>
keepalive -------------------o-----o-----o-----o---------------

When source is silent for 'time', keepalive triggers once every 'time'.
```

That isn't too hard, but I'm trying to work out how to make it work when the length of the `TimeSpan` also comes from an `IObservable` source...

```
times     t1---------------t2----------------------------------
          |t1>                  |.t2.>
source    -----------x--x--x---x-------------------------x----x
             |t1>|t1>                 |.t2.>|.t2.>|.t2.>
keepalive ---o---o--------------------o-----o-----o-----o------


When source is silent for 't1', keepalive triggers once every 't1', when
new time t2 is provided, the timeout and keepalive period is updated.
```

Comment: I know you’re answering your own Q here, but if you’re looking for alternative answers, a marble diagram may help with clarity and corner cases.

Comment: @Shlomo, better?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in response to your question and your answer.

You should try to avoid `.Publish()` when possible as it creates an `IConnectableObservable<T>` that can be a pain to manage. Where possible use the `.Publish(inner => ...)` overload that gives you a plain `IObservable<T>`.

In the main part of your query the `Merge`, `Throttle` and `Never` are all unnecessary.

You are right that you need a double `Switch`.

In your question and answer you didn't declare the types of observables - and it's a little unclear from your code. I'll assume that `source` is an `IObservable<long>` and that the final query is also `IObservable<long>` where `-1` is sent after each interval when the source didn't send.

Here's the code:

```
IObservable<long> source = ...
IObservable<TimeSpan> heartbeatTimes = ...

IObservable<long> query =
    source
        .Do(x => SendItem(x))
        .StartWith(0)
        .Publish(pxs =>
            heartbeatTimes
                .Select(t =>
                    pxs
                        .StartWith(0)
                        .Select(px => Observable.Interval(t).Select(x => -1L).StartWith(px))
                        .Switch())
                .Switch());
```

Here's my test code:

```
void Main()
{
    var random = new Random();
    IObservable<long> source = Observable.Generate(0L, x => x < 100L, x => x + 1L, x => x, x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.NextDouble() * 5.0));
    var heartbeatTimes = new Subject<TimeSpan>();
    
    IObservable<long> query = ...
    
    IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe(x => SendHeartbeat());
    
    heartbeatTimes.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0));
    heartbeatTimes.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
}

void SendHeartbeat()
{
    Console.Write("!");
}

void SendItem(long item)
{
    Console.Write($"{item}.");
}
```

My tests seemed to work as you wanted.

`heartbeatTimes` should be an observable that immediately produces a value otherwise the query won't return anything until it does.

Comment: This is great, thanks. The two outputs have different types, but I don't think it changes the logic, as far as the heartbeat is concerned, it could be Unit.Default.

Comment: hm, there are a few problems... For the first time, it needs bump starting by an incoming item. I moved the StartWith from after the Interval to after the Do which fixed that. The other problem is that if you send a new heartbeat, that also needs an incoming item to get it going. I'm going to carry on playing with it.

Comment: @Benjol - I did mention at the end of the answer that you need immediately produce a value from the `heartbeatTimes` observable. As long as that has a `StartWith` value then it works fine.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I've updated with working version. I'm still not sure which I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm quite proud of this, so if you're going to shoot it down, please do so gently :)

```
var items = source.Publish();
items.Subscribe(item => SendItem(item)); //not interesting, but for completeness' sake

heartbeatTimes.Select(time =>  //for each incoming heartbeat time
    //merge two sources, starts and stops, both derived from time:
    Observable.Merge(               
        //starts
        // (need initial value otherwise if no items, interval is never started)
        items.StartWith((0, null))     
            .Throttle(time)                        // when itemsource is silent for [time]
            .Select(_ => Observable.Interval(time) // start interval every [time]
                  // interval fires at end of [time], so send an initial trigger immediately
                 .StartWith(0)),                  
        //stops
        // as soon as a item comes, send Never (to replace Observable.Interval)
        items.Select(_ => Observable.Never<long>()) 
    ).Switch() //chose latest source from merged stops/starts
)
//switches from one start/stop source, to the next 
// (each time heartbeatTime produces a new value)
.Switch()  
.Subscribe(_ => SendHeartbeat());

items.Connect();
```

Comment: I'll try to be gentle.